# Module Not Found error :flask module not found

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

I am just doing a Python course on Udemy. This is the backend portion of the program,running on a virtual environment in visual studio code.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='postgresql://postgres:********@localhost/height-email_collector'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Data(db.Model):
    __tablename__ ="data"
    id =db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email_ =db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    height_ =db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, email_,height_):
        self.email_ = email_
        self.height_ = height_

@app.route("/")
def Index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/success", methods =['POST'])              
def success():
    if request.method=='POST':
        email = request.form["email_name"]
        height = request.form["height_name"]
        print(email, height)
        data = Data(email,height)
        db.session.add(data)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template('success.html')    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True 
    app.run()
```

When I execute the code,this is what I get:

```
(virtual) C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\My_Python\Py_html> py -3 App10.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "App10.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

Even I did reinstalled the packages ,but I am unable to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

In the console, when you are typing  `py -3 App10.py`, you are probably not using the python of the virtual env (where you installed Flask), but the default one (of your PATH).

If you created a virtual environment with virtualenv in the directory `C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\My_Python\venv` you might want to try something like:

```
C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\My_Python\venv\Scripts\python.exe App10.py
```